# Distinct queries in the Java Mongo aggregation framework?

Tags: java, mongodb

Could someone give me an example of how to perform a distinct query using the [Java Mongo aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/#java-driver-and-aggregation-framework)?

I don't see an example in the [official docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/#java-driver-and-aggregation-framework).

So for example, in the docs they have this example,

```
$group: { _id: "$department",
          average: { $avg: "$amount" } }
```

How would I add a distinct (say to field `building`) to that query?

Comment: Distinct [docs](http://bit.ly/12lpJ3k)?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, yeah I was looking at, the problem I have is what to use an aggregate query with a distinct. I can't see a way to blend the two.

Comment: Ahh. `$group: { _id : { department: "$department", building: "$building" } , .... }`

Comment: @WiredPrairie, if you didn't know the name of the building that wouldn't work. What I want would be an equivalent to a count distinct and group by in SQL.

Comment: use `buildings: {$addToSet:"$building"}` in the group (like you have avg.  That builds an array of unique values of building for that department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend your aggregation to include `building` with $addToSet operator:

```
 {$group: { _id: "$department",
          average: { $avg: "$amount" },
          buildings: { $addToSet: "$building"}
 }
```